# How to pass query-params in route's path?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm passing params from a Link in Post.js file to Route in App.js file. I  need to know how do i pass params in route's path so that it should be redirected to "ShowPost" component.

Thanks.

----- Post.js ---------------

`` <Link to={{ pathname: '/post', search: `?userId=${post.userId}`}}>{post.title}</Link> ``

-----App.js------------------

`<Route path="/post/:userId" component={ShowPost}/>`

i expect to be redirected to "ShowPost" component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
<Link to={`/post/${post.userId}`}>{post.title}</Link>
```

Comment: Thank you. got it. is there any way we can do 

<Route path="/post?userId=:id" component={ShowPost}/> ?